# Git: How do I remove HEAD back to most recent commit?

Tags: git, repository

Being a beginner in git, I somehow managed to spoil my repo in the way that it looks like that now:

```
PS C:\GitRepositories> git log --oneline

158e4c0 (HEAD -> 24d309, origin/24d309) Comment6
b4c156a Comment5
87bd801 Comment4
b24d309 (master) Comment3
f1ec7ee (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Comment2
6ce6a10 Comment1
```

Now, when I push the version of Comment2 is pushed, not the most recent one (Comment6). Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*blind guess* :

at some point, you tried to reach the state of your `master` branch (commit `b24d309`),
and you tried to do so by running `git checkout -b b24d309` (incidentally, you added a typo, but the issue in this case is actually using `-b`).

If you use `-b <something>` : `git` will understand that your intention is to create a branch, using `<something>` as its branchname.
If `<something>` happens to look like a commit hash (say: `24d309` or `b24d309`), well, you will end up with a branch which has a name that looks like a hash ...

---

If your intention is :

- to have `master` as your active branch
- to move `master` forward to "Comment6"
- to update `origin/master` to the same state
- to remove the existence of the ill named `24d309` branch (both local and remote)

you can do the following:

```
git switch master
git merge --ff-only 158e4c0
git push origin master

# remove local and remote branches:
git branch -D 24d309    # -D (upper D) is the "forced" option for -d
                        # see 'git help branch' for more details
git push origin -d 24d309
```